# How to block a Docker registry?

Tags: docker, registry, docker-registry

I want to block access to the default docker.io registry.  For security/IP protection, we need to block push/pull access to/from the public Docker hub.

There have been **many** attempts to make this a configuration option, but all PRs just keep getting rejected.  Red Hat has implemented both '--block-registry' and '--add-registry', which are **exactly** what I need, but it only works with Red Hat's fork of docker v1.10, and I want to use docker v1.12+

I'm using RHEL/Centos 7

DNS spoofing doesn't seem to work via the following in /etc/hosts (anymore):

```
127.0.0.1 index.docker.io registry.docker.io registry-1.docker.io docker.io
```

And I can't seem to get the firewall to block access either with the following rules (where the IPs are currently those from the above hosts listed in /etc/hosts):

```
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter OUTPUT                                                                           
0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j REJECT
0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.207.178.113 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.73.159.23 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 54.85.12.131 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.6.119.223 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.0.53.94 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 34.192.123.224 -j DROP
0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT
2 -j REJECT
```

or

```
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-rules ipv4 filter FORWARD
0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j REJECT
0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.207.178.113 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.73.159.23 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 54.85.12.131 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.6.119.223 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 52.0.53.94 -j DROP
0 -p tcp -m tcp -d 34.192.123.224 -j DROP
```

With all these in place, I can still search/pull from docker.io.

One of the PRs to resolve this got closed by a maintainer who said it looks like something that should be addressed by the firewall.  Can someone please tell me how this can actually be done?

Comment: The firewall blocks are probably not working because we use a corporate web proxy.  Is there any way to block the registry access without it being done on at the proxy level (i.e. for the whole organization)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this to /etc/hosts on Ubuntu worked for me:

```
0.0.0.0 index.docker.io auth.docker.io registry-1.docker.io dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net production.cloudflare.docker.com
```

I got the list of domains from here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015442847-Whitelisting-Docker-Hub-Hosts-for-Firewalls-and-HTTP-Proxy-Servers

Answer (score 5):

On redhat/centos add

```
--block-registry docker.io
```

to wherever you start your docker engine from ( likely `/etc/sysconfig/docker` on redhat, or possibly `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` )

don't forget to refresh `systemd` if you edited the service file ( `systemctl daemon-reload` ) and to restart the docker engine ( `systemctl restart docker.service` ) in either case

now if you do a `ps auxwwf | grep docker` the docker engine --block-register flag should appear in the process listing.

I came here because this does not work on debian/ubuntu, and am looking for a way to do this on debian.  = / HTH

Comment: Could You please add link to documentation? AFAIK option `--block-registry` was refused by Docker team - see https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/10411