# How to list locally configured Docker Container registeries

Tags: linux, docker, docker-container

I apologize for naive question. I am using my personal docker registry. I need to disable global docker registry. How to list the configure remote registries and disable one of them?

I searched on google but did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Docker daemon can connect with any docker registry in the world, if the registry has a valid HTTPS certificate. There is no "list", just like there is no list of like all web pages in the world.

> disable one of them?

Setup a firewall, remove the dns names, setup a https proxy that filters the traffic, etc. [How to block a Docker registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578045/how-to-block-a-docker-registry)